# Playing a movie in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I get the following error while trying to show a movie:

```
cv2.imshow("Video Output", frames)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

The commented-out lines are my attempts to fix the problem, but I still get the error.
What am i doing wrong?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("resources/Plaza.mp4")
while True:
    frames = vid.read()
    # frames = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    # frames_arr = np.array(frames)
    cv2.imshow("Video Output", frames)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better implementation would be:

- 1. Check if the video is opened using `vid.isOpened()`

  - ```py
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture("resources/Plaza.mp4")
    while vid.isOpened():
    ```
- 2. If the frame is returned successfully then display it.

  - ```py
    ret, frames = vid.read()

    if ret:
        # frames = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        # frames_arr = np.array(frames)
        cv2.imshow("Video Output", frames)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    ```
- 3. Make sure always close all the windows and release the `VideoCapture` object

  - ```
    cv2.destoyAllWindows()
    vid.release()
    ```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("resources/Plaza.mp4")
while vid.isOpened():
    ret, frames = vid.read()

    if ret:
        # frames = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        # frames_arr = np.array(frames)
        cv2.imshow("Video Output", frames)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else
        # continue with the next frame
        continue

cv2.destoyAllWindows()
vid.release()
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `vid.read()` returns two values. The first contains a boolean value, which, according to the [documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera):

> returns a bool (True/False). If frame is read correctly, it will be True. So you can check end of the video by checking this return value.

So your `frames` variable essentially is a tuple containing the boolean and the frames themselves. You need to index in to the second element (`frames[1]`) to play the video with `imshow`.

Always read the docs well!